# conditional @import in .less or no error when file missing

Tags: less

I need to conditionally import a file during a particular type of build. Using `grunt-contrib-jshint@0.7.0` which is on top of `less@1.4.2`

What I tried thus far...

Trying to use protected mixins to determine the type of build I require and namely, to skip imports of certain less files that break in dev mode.

```
@isProduction: 1;

...

.getImports() when (@isProduction = 1){
}

.getImports() {
    @import "productionStyles";
}

...
.getImports();
```

however, this seems to fail and it tries to import and parse `productionStyles.less` all the time. I guess protected mixins does not cover `@import`, so how would you solve that?

I also tried

```
@productionStyles: "productionStyles"; // or 0

...
@productionStyles: 0;


.getImports() when not (@productionStyles = 0){
    @import "@{productionStyles}";
}

...
```

to same avail, it will try to import it anyway `>> FileError: '0.less' wasn't found in ...`.

I am starting to think it will need a bigger refactor where `devStyles` and `productionStyles` are both a thing and I just switch between them - it's just that productionStyles was an addition that can only compile after a full build due to deps and I would much rather solve this by compiling conditionally.

I can also move away from using `grunt-contrib-jshint` and write my own less parser but would like to explore the built-in options first.

As the `productionStyle.less` references several files that are not in the file system, is it possible to ignore the `@imports` that fail and continue building? I would prefer not to disable error checking/break on all errors due to possible parser errors elsewhere...

Comment: why not to use different versions of `productionStyles.less` for different environments?

Answer (score 3):

I've solved your problem using [switch parameter](http://lesscss.org/#-pattern-matching-and-guard-expressions):

*index.html*

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css"  href="style.less" />
      <script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      [foo]
    </body>
  </html>
```

*style.less*

```
.mixin(production) {
  @import "test.less";
  background: @color;
}

.mixin(dev) {
  background: green;
}

html {
  .mixin(production);
}
```

*test.less*

```
@color: red;
```

*less.js* is less v1.4.1 downloaded straight from [project page](https://raw.github.com/less/less.js/master/dist/less-1.4.1.min.js).

Code about should result in red background. 
Switching to `html { .mixin(dev); }` disables `@import` and background turns green.

It's possible that your solution would work, too, but you have errors in HTML or something like that - I haven't checked that.